# Moving database from local MYSQL database to MAMP MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, apache

I've been developing websites on my local computer. I used the already installed apache server and php. I downloaded MySql and used that. I decided to use MAMP. I installed it but now when I go to phpmyadmin it goes to the MAMP mysql databases. If I shut off MAMP and start my local apace server and mysql and go to phpmyadmin, it still goes to the new collection of databases. Is there a file that I can copy or how can I get my old databases transferred to my new collection of databases.

I have a hard time understanding the process so excuse my ignorance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a local phpmyadmin (otherwise take a look at [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)). You can simply export your local databases and import them into the MAMP Database via MAMP PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I did have a local phpmyadmin but when I try to access that my databases are not there

Comment: MAMP uses its own PhpMyAdmin and MySQL. If you run MAMP on standard Ports (80, 3306) you won't be able to access your local phpmyadmin via default ports

Comment: I have mamp MySQL port as 8889

Comment: Can you access your local database via command line? Then try using mysqldump

Comment: I type mysql in my terminal window it says -bash: mysql: command not found

Comment: Try /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql in your terminal in case you have no alias setup (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-notes.html)

Comment: I type that in and it says no such file or directory

Comment: I went to the folder and it was there...so I double clicked and it took me to the mysql command line